# Programmatically changing the decimal separator with C setlocale()

Tags: c, setlocale

First of all, this must be really solved in C, and with UNIX standard C functions (because of project constraints). So, C++ or alternative libraries are outside the scope of the question.

I know how to set the default user locale with setlocale, as well as setting the standard C/POSIX locales.

However, I'm in a situation where the decimal separator is file-specified, so I want my program to temporally change the decimal separator.

LC_NUMERIC expects a locale name... but I don't want to give it a locale name, but the separator character directly.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm afraid you won't like the solution :)

First of all, since you're operating with `setlocale` you have to supply a locale name. Therefore there should be a locale with LC_NUMERIC property defined by you in the time of program execution. Therefore you need to define a new locale. You may define it with [localedef](http://man.cx/localedef%281%29) You may use [this doc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales#Testing_Locales) as a guide for making and using a new locale and [this site](http://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/en_US/) to get source files which you can use as a template for your custom locale definition.

Comment: Indeed, I don't like it, however, the reason isn't the amount of work, but the fact that it involves creating system files that must be installed in the user machine. If a new locale could be set up programmatically from inside an application without using locale files, it would be fine for me.

Comment: No. Take a look at the example above. They describe techniques how to compile and _use_ a locale without installing it to the system folder.

Comment: Generally the recipe involves creation of a temporary folder ([mkdtemp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdtemp)), storing locale definition files into that folder, "compilation" and subsequent usage of the new locale, again, from the temporary directory. Maybe it would take less efforts to use some custom number formatting functions which wouldn't require locale per se, but rather some configurable formatting. However if you wish/have to stay with locale stuff, I'm affraid you have no other choice.